# Load in different javascript files

Tags: javascript

I found a javascript loading function like this:

```
function loadScript(srcs, f) {

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    var done = false;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // attach to both events for cross browser finish detection:
        if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {
            done = true;
            if (typeof f === 'function') 
                f();
            // cleans up a little memory:
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
};
```

It works very well for loading one file, now I want to modify the function so that it can load in an arrays of file. I have code like this:

```
function loadScript(srcs, f) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    for ( var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++ ) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = srcs[i];
        var done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // attach to both events for cross browser finish detection:
            if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {
                done = true;
                if (typeof f === 'function') 
                    f();
                // cleans up a little memory:
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
            }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
};
```

Now if I call this function like this:

```
loadScript( ['testing_path1', 'testing_path2'], function() {


} );
```

Even though the testing_path2 file is loaded, I can't call the functions within it. I am thinking it's because of the asynchronous feature of javascript. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: And you sure it is still there? (Referring to the `head/removeChild(script)` bit).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of this line in your code:

```
head.removeChild(script);
```

Otherwise the `script` tag gets immediately removed again.